# How to apply a one-to-one mapping of cpu cores in qemu/kvm?

Tags: linux, qemu, kvm

I reserved three of my four CPU cores for a qemu/kvm instance by using cpusets. However this does not prevent the process scheduler from executing three virtual cores on one physical core if cpu usage is low, right?

Is there a way to map each virtual CPU core to exactly one physical core? A solution **not** using libvirt/virsh would be highly appreciated since I am using plain qemu with kvm.

As far as I understand, this would improve cache locality as well latency caused by moving the process to another core. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may tweak some libvirt settings to define specific processor affinities?? Since as per the libvirt homepage [here](http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html), ***The libvirt KVM/QEMU driver can manage any QEMU emulator from version 0.8.1 or later***

setting KVM processor affinities is explained [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/ch25s06.html)

As QEMU does not seem to provide any switches upfront to lock cores, perhaps playing around with the backend might be what you would want to look at??